# Kernel of homomorphism/Normal Subgroup for nxn matrices under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

how to find a normal subgroup for nxn invertible matries under multiplication where n >=2. it should have determinant of -1? I have chosen 2X2 matrices g = (a b 0 c)belongs to G,h = (1 x 0 1) belongs to H with determinant -1 to prove ghg-1 = h belongs to H. But Do i need to find kernal of homomorphism to prove it? could someone explain with example matrices

Comment: The set of matrices of determinant $-1$ is not a subgroup of invertibles.  It's not even closed under multiplication.

Comment: @Randall i think i didnt compose the question properly.  Let n ≥ 2. Recall that GLn(R) is the set of invertible n by n matrices with entries in R, and that GLn(R) is a group under matrix multiplication. Find a normal subgroup H of GLn(R) such that H 6= GLn(R) and H contains all the matrices of GLn(R) that have determinant −1. prove that your H is in fact a normal subgroup.

Comment: @Art As stated in your comment, you could simply take $H$ to be the kernel of an appropriate homomorphism, say $A \mapsto |\det(A)|$, for instance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)